# Where to store large files when external storage is not writable?

Tags: android, file, caching, storage

I want to cache some files to be previewed later. The Android documentation says that you can store files in your cache directory by calling getCacheDir() but you should save a maximum of 1 MB approximately.

So, as the title says: Where should I store large files when external storage is not writable?

Comment: 1: That's imposible due to my app business because I need offline storage, 2: I can't assume that my users would have only modern devices, 3: Although some devices have built-in sdcard it may be possible that it can't be writable, so that is an incorrect assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the external storage is not available, your only options are:

- Wait for it to become available
- Save it to the internal storage, as cache or in the internal directory
- Save it into the cloud on your own or some other service's servers

There simple aren't any other options, and you will have to pick one of these.